# Ideas of how to fix this deadlock in NSSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, macos-high-sierra

As of macOS 10.13.2, the following simple Cocoa app app causes a deadlock on the main thread (and we never see the NSAlert):

AppDelegate.swift:

```swift
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    let text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit, phasellus elementum lobortis quisque aptent leo a, rutrum dictum velit nostra viverra mollis. Nam pharetra feugiat sollicitudin quisque consequat suspendisse nisi blandit purus nascetur proin mi, fermentum magna felis et aenean condimentum ultrices justo vulputate etiam fusce, turpis id netus tristique porta libero hendrerit scelerisque semper fringilla placerat. Accumsan nisl felis nascetur lorem vulputate metus mauris aliquet purus, rutrum non viverra dictumst mi commodo mollis risus, sociis ullamcorper integer tincidunt donec himenaeos porta vestibulum. Senectus torquent per odio viverra mauris dui lacus nisi ligula porta pretium ornare purus amet, ad cursus suspendisse dis porttitor nec enim class nunc leo ante cras tempor. Mollis posuere cum gravida a primis et donec mauris, sagittis sit duis nulla hac penatibus imperdiet amet montes, libero mattis blandit urna orci fringilla vestibulum. Vehicula porta tempor augue fringilla fames pellentesque feugiat sagittis, quis lobortis lectus phasellus class sapien vulputate senectus, volutpat duis erat tellus fusce ultricies morbi. Id cubilia malesuada consectetur quisque tempus mattis a, vulputate aliquet elementum non laoreet penatibus auctor, hac ad neque pharetra magnis amet."

    var synth: NSSpeechSynthesizer?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())/\(UUID().uuidString).aiff")

        synth = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
        synth?.startSpeaking(text, to: url)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
            self.synth?.stopSpeaking()
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.messageText = "After 'stopSpeaking'"
            alert.runModal()
        }
    }
}
```

This issue didn't exist before macOS 10.13.2, as far as I can tell. There are a lot of ways I can get the speech synthesizer to deadlock; the above code is the simplest reproduction case.

I filed a Radar (36138159) (https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4990843182120960) but I'm curious to know if anyone else has had any luck fixing this issue.

An added note: once I get this deadlock, I have to kill lingering `com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd` processes or else *anything* I try to do with NSSpeechSynthesizer causes a deadlock.

Comment: Thank you for your tip to `killall com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd`. I have been rebooting my computer to do a reset. Unfortunately I get into this state also via using `say` command on certain text files together with `-o` option.

Comment: I filed a support incident for this one with Apple. Will keep you updated.

Comment: Apple rejected my support incident and requested to file a bug report instead, which I did. There has been no reply from Apple. I have asked two times for an update. I tested the issue again on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G65). The problem persists.

Comment: I did not have the problem when using the voices tom and anna. I can reproduce the problem always with alex. Deleting and re-installing alex did not help.